# Converting boolean to bit at npgsql level

Tags: npgsql

I am looking forward for a configuration changes at **ngpsql level** which converts **boolean value(true/false)** from .Net Application **to bit value(1,0) for PostgreSQL**operation. The User inputs true/false from GUI.This has to be converted to 1 or 0 as PostgreSQL supports only 1 and 0 as bit values. Can this mapping be achieved during npgsql level ?

npsql version 4.0
Visual studio 2015

Comment: The natural way to represent true/false in PostgreSQL is with boolean - not bit (which is usually used by people coming from SQL Server). PostgreSQL bit is about bit strings, i.e. a series of bits.

Comment: Npgsql will not do any automatic conversion of .NET boolean to PostgreSQL bit (because of the above). You can always perform the conversion yourself in C# code. Otherwise, try to post a bit more info (or a code sample) to show what you're trying to do.